# Error while importing a ".sql" file in database

Tags: mysql, query, import

I am trying to import a .sql file in to my local database. whenever i type the command to import the file, I get an error `ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\S'.`

This is the first line of the sql file `update product set aka = 'Trojan.gen,Backdoor.Win32.Agent.bisn' where id = 156701`

Comment: The file must be in ASCII format. Also, SQL is pretty bad at telling you where the line actually ends, so look in the file for a `\S` string.

Comment: What's your exact command that you are typing in?

Comment: what kind of database?

Comment: Its a Mysql Database I am typing `mysql -hIP -uroot -p DN_name < filename.sql`

Comment: check that your sql command in script propertly ended with ";" or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have an ASCII file, the script could be giving problems because it is came from a Windows machine and you are attempting to load it into mysql on a Linux machine.

You may want to try one of two things:

- Using the mysql client in Windows, [load the data remotely](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17318/877).
- Use sql client in raw mode in one of two ways

  - `mysql -hIP -r -uroot -p DN_name < filename.sql`
  - `mysql -hIP -B -uroot -p DN_name < filename.sql`

Comment: ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'IP'

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use **path/to/file.sql** instead of **path\to\file.sql**

and "**database < path/to/file.sql**" didn't work for me for some reason - I had to use "**use database;**" and "**source path/to/file.sql;**".